Apache Kafka Server Configuration (Consumers and Producers are in different machines)
I'm testing Apache Kafka between 2 vps. (First vps IP: x.x.x.x and Second vps IP: y.y.y.y) Os course I've installed zookeeper and kafka server on both of them and are same producer and consumer file Here are producer.py and consumer.py codebase:
(First VPS)
Producer.py:
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json
# Initialize a Kafka Producer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['x.x.x.x:9092'],
                         api_version=(0,10),
                         value_serializer=lambda x: json.dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))

# Send a message
message = {"data": "from first message"}
producer.send('first', value=message)

# Ensure all messages are sent
producer.flush()

Consumer.py:
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import json

# Initialize a Kafka Consumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer('second',
                         bootstrap_servers=['y.y.y.y:9092'],
                         auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                         api_version=(0, 10),
                         value_deserializer=lambda x: json.loads(x.decode('utf-8')))

# Print received messages
for message in consumer:
    print(message.value)

(Second VPS)
Producer.py:
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json
# Initialize a Kafka Producer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['y.y.y.y:9092'],
                         api_version=(0,10),
                         value_serializer=lambda x: json.dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))

# Send a message
message = {"data": "from second message"}
producer.send('second', value=message)

# Ensure all messages are sent
producer.flush()

Consumer.py:
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import json

# Initialize a Kafka Consumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer('first',
                         bootstrap_servers=['x.x.x.x:9092'],
                         auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                         api_version=(0, 10),
                         value_deserializer=lambda x: json.loads(x.decode('utf-8')))

# Print received messages
for message in consumer:
    print(message.value)

Current status:

When ran producer file in First VPS, I can receive message on consumer in Second VPS
But when ran producer file in Second VPS, I can't receive any message on consumer in First VPS.
I think it's Apache Kafka Server Configuratioin why Second VPS doesn't work, since codebase are same.

Thanks
I'd like to receive message in Second VPS from first VPS.

You'll need to share server config if you think that's the problem. By default, Kafka only listens on the local machine, yes

Thanks for reply, Current, I'm using default Kafka settings. In this case, what is need additional configuration?

And I just installed Kafka server and using now.

To create a proper cluster, you need to edit listeners and advertised.listeners. The reason you wouldn't receive messages is if you didn't actually create a cluster and just have two separate kafka servers that aren't linked (the Zookeeper connection address will need to match as well) Please [edit] your question, and reply here, not try to message me on external apps

Great! I just checked listeners and advertised.listeners Kafka Server. properties file (default value: localhost)

Advertised listeners needs to be the external IP / hostname of each server and listeners should be PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092 to allow all external connections

What's your kafka server start command actually look like? You mention you installed Zookeeper, but Zookeeper mode doesn't use the Kraft config files you're modifying. And I assume you're restarting the brokers each time?

It's first time Apache Kafka for me and I've installed with this guide: https://shape.host/resources/apache-kafka-installation-guide-ubuntu-22-04
This is kafka server start command: sudo systemctl start kafka
I'd like to know more detail.

That's using /opt/kafka/config/server.properties rather than the kraft file you've been updating and you would use sudo systemctl restart kafka after making any change

/opt/kafka/config/server.properties
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R9GHQ11Qc8N5MEATr3cK1NYYcJtXqkvKNUDT9TPxXFg/edit?usp=sharing

As you can see, there is no listeners and advertised.listeners attributes in this file.

Yes they are. They're after broker.id and commented out. You'll need to remove the comment from the lines https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/server.properties#L34

I just fixed like this:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R9GHQ11Qc8N5MEATr3cK1NYYcJtXqkvKNUDT9TPxXFg/edit?usp=sharing
Please take a look of this.

That's the minimum changes needed unless you actually want to create a multi node cluster for high availability and replication (which kafka is meant for). Then, you'll have edit zookeeper.connect to reference both VPS Zookeeper servers and change broker.id on both VPS to be a unique number

Perfect!
If First VPS(Public IP - x.x.x.x) is only Producer (Installed Kafka server) and Second VPS is only Consumer (Not installed Kafka Server), is this zookeeper.connect=x.x.x.x:2181?

The location of clients isn't important for Zookeeper  configuration. If one server runs both Zookeeper and kafka, you'd use localhost. If you want to form a two node cluster, you'd put x.x.x.x:2181,y.y.y.y:2181 (but an even number of Zookeepers causes its own issues)
